# Time among computers and servers are off

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, time, windows-server

I'm trying to get all my computers time to sync.
I have a Windows Server 2012 with hyper-V. Running on the Hyper V is:

1. a VM DC - parent Hyper-V is part of DC's domain
2. a VM IIS server (workgroup)

I have some Windows 10 computers in workgroup and others connected to the domain

The Hyper V server, VM IIS server, and VM DC times do match.

I synced both the VM IIS server and a workgroup Windows 10 computer at the same time using time.nist.gov as the source. Both did not change and reported successful updates yet the time remains 6-7 mins different.

**I'm assuming the VM IIS server uses the parent Hyper V time but then why does it give the option to sync with internet time?**

**Do I setup the VM DC with an external time source so that the times start syncing correctly?**

---

My end solution was a combination of the accepted answer (disabled the time service integration feature for the VM DC) and [setup / pushed an external time service group policy](https://theitbros.com/configure-ntp-time-sync-group-policy/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply need to uncheck the **Time synchronization** option from the **Integration Services** settings of the VMs in Hyper-V, and set each VM to synchronize their times from a reliable source manually one by one.

You could force all workgroup computers to use NTP from a local NTP server which is configured and confirmed to have the correct time in the workgroup, and force all domain computers to use NTP from a domain controller—maybe all can use the domain controller for NTP for sync from workgroup and the domain if the time is accurate for your needs.

I had an issue with a Hyper-V Server once that wasn't configured properly for NTP and the time on it got out of sync due to the **Time synchronization** setting being checked so I unchecked that option on the Hyper-V host, and then set the important VMs to sync their time from a reliable NTP source instead—a domain controller in that case.

> **Note:** A bad CMOS battery can cause the machine time to get out of sync too.

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Windows Time Service Tools and Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings)
- [Configure DC to synchronize time with external NTP server](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/65413-configure-dc-to-synchronize-time-with-external-ntp-server)